# Save workbook with date in cell

Tags: excel, vba

Back again with another question.

I want to save my workbook with the date the data is from, not today's date.

This is what I have so far and it saves with today's date:

```
Sub Save_New_Workbook()

Dim CurrDate As String

CurrDate = Format(Date, "DDMMYYYY")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Macros\Results Macro\" & fName & "SMS" & fName & " - " & 
CurrDate & ".xlsm" _


End Sub
```

The date I want to save the file as instead would be in cell F2. Any tips?

Comment: `CurrDate = Format(Range("F2").Value, "DDMMYYYY")`

Comment: usually `Dim CurrDate As String` causes problems, try `Dim CurrDate As Date`

Comment: In cell `F2` of which worksheet in which workbook? What is `fName`? Have you just copied a worksheet from another workbook creating a single-worksheet workbook and you're trying to save it with a name according to the worksheet's name and the date in its `F2` cell? Please add the clarifying and any additional information (more relevant code) to your post. Also, you need to consider using the `SaveAs` method `FileFormat` parameter `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` used for `.xlsm` files if the workbook has a different file extension (incl. when it has not been saved yet).

Comment: To add to what @braX posted - `CurrDate = Format(Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Value, "DDMMYYYY")`.  Always be specific about where the cell you're looking at is located.  `Thisworkbook` is the file that the code is in.